# Django profile showing percentage complete

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user profile model. I would like a new **model method** gives me a score on how completed the profile is. For example:

```
Name 10%
Mobile 50%
Gender 10%
Website 10%
Location 10%
birth_date 10%
```

Meaning, if the user had filled in **name** and **mobile** their profile would be **60%** complete.

**Could someone get me started on how I would accomplished such a thing?** Thanks:

**My Model:**

```
class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    """ Default profile """
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (1, _('Male')),
        (2, _('Female')),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='profile')

    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('gender'),
                                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                                              blank=True,
                                              null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(_('website'), blank=True, )
    location = models.CharField(_('location'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(_('birth date'), blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach could be:

```
class Profile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    #attributes

    @property 
    def percentage_complete(self):
        percent = { 'name': 10, 'mobile': 50, 'website': 10, 'location': 10, 'birth_date': 10, 'gender': 10}
        total = 0
        if self.gender:
            total += percent.get('gender', 0)
        if self.name:
            total += percent.get('name', 0)
        #and so on
        return "%s"%(total)
```

and then `profile.percentage_complete` gives you the completeness. Since you are managing the dictionary, you have complete control over the weights and the value is assured to be the percentage.

Comment: would you make that a @property?

Comment: well.. not necessary, but sure. Are you planning to do anything else with it ?

Comment: There could be times where I need to overwrite some values or do special stuff with yes.

Answer (score 0):

Working on one project where i have to calculate model completeness on a couple of models here is my take how i have approached the problem using django signals. We could take this example further by defining the models in django settings.py. As well as handling model relationships.

```
class UserProfile(UserenaLanguageBaseProfile):
    complete_progress = { 'name': 10, 'mobile': 50, 'website': 10, 'location': 10, 'birth_date': 10, 'gender': 10}


# If this is too heavy best put this in a background task celery
@receiver(post_save)
def model_completeness_listener(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    list_of_models = [UserProfile, CustomerProfile]
    if sender in list_of_models:
        complete_progress = 0.0
        total_weight = 0.0
        for field in instance.completeness:
        try:
            total_weight += instance.completeness[field]
                if getattr(instance, field):
                    complete_progress += instance.completeness[field]
        except AttributeError:
            continue

        overall_completeness = (complete_progress/total_weight) * 100
        print "------------%s---------------" % (sender.__name__)
        print "[progress weight : %d total weight : %d overall completeness : %d]" % (complete_progress, total_weight, overall_completeness)
        print "-----------------------------"
```

Do something with overall_completeness percent value either assign it to the profile model or store it somewhere else